# A mathematic insights to Calendar.

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Last Christmas, a kid in my neighborhood dressed in a pirate suit and knocked my door for "trick or treat". He explained to me that Dec 25, which is 25 written in base 10, is equal to 31 in base 8, which is Oct 31. So ingeniously, Halloween coincides with Christmas.

I really wonder which other two dates would possibly coincides with each other.

Can you help me find them? And explain what kind the two dates are. Your birthday is also appreciated.

Comment: I assume in this sense, we assume December = 10, October = 8, and July & August don't really count for anything?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer In early roman empire, new year start at March 1st. December is actually the $10^{th}$ and October is the $8^{th}$ month. January and February doesn't exist until around 700BC.

Comment: Some years, Thanksgiving falls on Nov. $23.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point in the original "date identity" is that the abbreviations  Dec and Oct for the month names are also interpreted as abbreviations for the base, i.e., "decimal 25 = octal 31" becomes "Dec 25 = Oct 31". There is no month name abbreviated as Bin or Hex, for example, so binary and hexadecimal can be excluded. Indeed, at best we might be somewhat willing to accept Sep for septimal (base 7) and Nov for novemal(?) (base 9). However, these are far from common enough to be understood from such abbreviations (and I am not even sure about the correct adjective forms).

Nevertheless, in September, we have dates Sep 01, ..., Sep 06, Sep 10, ..., Sep 30 which can be seen as standing for the numbers one up to twenty-one.
In October, we have accordingly the numbers one up to twenty-five, in November the numbers one up to twenty-seven, and in December of course the numbers one up to thirty-one. Now you can pick any number that is common to at least two months and form such date equalities accordingly, e.g.,

> Sep 01 = Oct 01 = Nov 01 = Dec 01

or

> Sep 10 = Oct 07 = Nov 07 = Dec 07

or

> Sep 30 = Oct 25 = Nov 23 = Dec 21

or

> Oct 26 = Nov 24 = Dec 22

or

> Nov 30 = Dec 27

and all cases in-between.

Answer (score 0):

**which other two dates would possibly coincide with each other**

> There are too many to list out.

Maybe you could find them using converting decimal number to octal number. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-decimal-to-octal) is the rules you can follow to find. My birthday is `01 jan` which is same in binary, octal and hexadecimal system .